# $1 means for .... ? without any input?

Tags: bash, shell

I have one program that starts with this line. What does this mean? I am having trouble googling because of the dollar sign.

How come $1 without any parameters? And what does it mean by -d here?

```
  if [ -d $1 ]; then
```

And does semi-colon come even if the if-condition does not even start? I thought semi-colon comes only at the end of statement or at the end of condition like

```
   if () {  };
```

Comment: You might find this useful instead of using Google for such problems: http://symbolhound.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The semicolon is required, because without an indication of where that context ends (through a semicolon, newline, etc), `if` cannot know where the condition ends, and the conditional block begins. Compare:

```
$ if echo then foo then; then :; fi
then foo then
$ if echo then; then :; fi
then
```

`-d` is a test to check if the next argument is a directory. From `help test` (because `test` is equivalent to `[`):

```
-d FILE        True if file is a directory.
```

For example:

```
$ mkdir foo
$ if [ -d foo ]; then
>     echo foo is a dir
> fi
foo is a dir
```

`$1` is the first argument passed to your program. For example:

```
$ cat > script << 'EOF'
> #!/bin/sh  
> echo "$1"
> EOF
$ chmod +x script
$ ./script foo
foo
```

As an aside, you should quote `$1` here, because otherwise it can expand into multiple arguments, resulting in a syntax error from `[`:

```
$ dir="foo bar"
$ [ -d $dir ]
sh: 2: [: foo: unexpected operator
$ [ -d "$dir" ]
$
```